# Database schema for titles and partner titles

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-design, relational-database, database-schema

I have a standard Title table having below structure:

```
TitleId       Title
-----------------------------
7282991         CEO
7282992         CTO
7282993         SSE
7282994         SE
7282995         CFO
```

Now we have a requirements that users can add their own custom titles along with these standard titles. So I created a table like below.

```
  TitleId       Title     UserId
------------------------------------
7282991         Manager          1
7282992         Team Lead        1
7282993         QA               1
7282994         Admin            2
7282995         FO               2
```

Now problem I am facing is I have to show the all standard titles and user's custom titles in a dropdown list in a UI. To do that I have to make a union operation between standard table and custom table for titles. Also when a title will be assigned to an employee I have to check that titleId in 2 tables to find that its a standard or custom title.

What can be the best schema for this so that It will make my task easy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could keep all titles in the same table, just add a column to flag non standar ones.

```
TitleId       Title       IsStandard
```

I would also add a unique index on the Title column to avoid duplicate values.

If the relationship is many to many, the final model could be something like this diagram[image]

Comment: Thanks for taking interest but how I will came to know which title belongs to which user?

Comment: @ChupChapCharli If a user can have only a single title, then just add a TitleId column to your User table. If otherwise users can have many titles, use a join table UserTitles having UserId and TitleId columns, with the respective foreign keys

Comment: yes, user can have multiple titles but Can't I add UserId in above table you proposed and for standard it will be null and for other will have specific use value, instead of doing it from 2 tables.

Comment: @ChupChapCharli I have updated my answer with a diagram, hope you get mi point now.

Comment: You forget to add IsStandard column in Title table as I have to show all standard plus user specific titles. Please suggest.